# why my command on my details page won't work

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Basic of my app : i have a TasksGroup which contains multiple Tasks.

Currently in my TasksDetailsPage which opens up when i click an item in the list view, has a delete button which has a deletecommand.

The problem is that this delete command is never fired ( i added a breakpoint).

This is what i see in the console : DeleteTaskCommand' property not found on 'Calculette.Models.Tasks', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Button.Command'.

I don't really understand why it search in Models.Tasks.

Here's my code, thanks for the help !

**How my ListView is set in TasksGroupPage.xaml**

```
<ListView  x:Name="TasksListView" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected" ItemsSource="{Binding Taches, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

**What i use to send the data to my TasksDetailsPage in the TasksGroupPage.xaml.cs**

```
async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        var taskSelected = e.SelectedItem as Tasks;

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new TasksDetailsPage(taskSelected)
        {
            BindingContext = taskSelected
        });
    }
}
```

**My TasksDetailsPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class TasksDetailsPage : ContentPage
    {
        Tasks task;
        public TasksDetailsPage (Tasks task)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.task = task;
    
            BindingContext = new TasksDetailsPageViewModel(task);
        }
}
```

**My TasksDetailsPage.xaml button that fire the command**

```
        <Button Text="Delete" x:Name="DeleteButton"  TextColor="#008A00" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="#1A961A" Command="{Binding DeleteTaskCommand}"></Button>
```

**TasksDetailsPageViewModel.cs which contains the delete command**

```
    public Command DeleteTaskCommand { get; set; }

   public TasksDetailsPageViewModel(Tasks task)
    {
        
        DeleteTaskCommand = new Command(async () => await DeleteTask(task), () => !IsBusy);
        
    }



        async Task DeleteTask(Tasks task)
        {
            bool isUserAccept = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Détails de la tâche", "Supprimer la tâche", "OK", "Cancel");

            if(isUserAccept)
            {
                await App.Database.DeleteTaskAsync(task);
            }
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is, that you set the binding context to the Task and not to the viewmodel.

```
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new TasksDetailsPage(taskSelected)
    {
        BindingContext = taskSelected //delete this line
    });
```

What happens?

- The TasksDetailsPage is created via constructor where you set the BindingContext to `TasksDetailsPageViewModel`
- **afterwards** `BindingContext = taskSelected` is executed and sets the BindingContext to the Model.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, this worked but if i remove that line, my details page is not filled up with any data ? How to fix thanks :)

Comment: Then your detailpage was built based on this bug / behavoir ^^ You have to update the bindings of the detail page.

Comment: Ohh so i have a bug somewhere else ? :/

Comment: I assume the detailpage bindings where written in the precondition, that the bindingcontext is a `Tasks` and not a `TasksDetailsPageViewModel`. Just check every binding of the detailpage and check if the property exists on your viewmodel. If the viewmodel doesn’t  have the property, you either have to create it or you can expose the Tasks as a single property and update each binding to use this one

Comment: Btw: don't forget the mark the stackoverflow answer as accepted and give it an upvote. Also for your other questions you have asked here on stackoverflow. Thanks!

Comment: Can we open a chat for the other problem real quick if you don't mind haha ? Would be nice to have this fixed. Thanks !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217407/discussion-between-codejourney-and-sven-michael-stube).